# Running a Python script with sudo in Vscode

Tags: linux, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I'd like to know (I am programming student) how to run in **VSCODE** *sudo* permissions because the script I have to run to test requires it. It's in **python**. I also need to run some arguments in it ('sniff'). I am using linux.

Comment: The documentation mentions "If you need to run a shell command with elevated (administrator) or different permissions, you can use platform utilities such as `runas.exe` within a terminal." https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_windows

Comment: My bad. I didn't mention that I am on linux...

Comment: that's okay. does your *entire* python script need to run with root permissions, or only *some* commands within the script (e.g. `os.popen()`)?

Comment: I found it there. thanks. He uses ngrep and a sniff argument while running. It's not mine, I want to refactor it and understand the code... I think i did.

Comment: you found the answer (how to do it)? if yes, you can put answer in the answer box below and accept :)

Comment: So to add sniff i would do the same in settings?

Comment: i think yes, if the setting works for `ngrep` it should also work for `sniff`, if those are both `os` commands

Answer (score 0):

I found the partial answer. `// Linux
"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.linux": ["-l"]` in the *settings* for the admin permissions.

[Integrated Terminal - VSCode Docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_windows)

Answer (score 0):

Docs state just use the sudo attribute as set to true. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging

i.e.

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal", 
            "sudo": true
        }
    ]
}
```